# Will a newly released package be pushed to my machine?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I am not sure *if, how and when* a new package that was added to an Ubuntu repository finds its way to my machine as an installed package *unless* I explicitly install it.

For example, what if Ubuntu `18.04` is released, but one week later, Canonical realize that they forgot to include package `foo`. Including package `foo` is absolutely critical, because there is a cronjob running every night calling a command included only in package `foo`. So until this package rolls out to all Ubuntu 18.04 machines, they will continue to crash every midnight.

As another example, the latest and greatest release runs just fine, until Canonical learns that there exists a ginormous security hole which can only be "patched" by installing a new package `bar`.

As far as my understanding goes, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt upgrade` focus on upgrading already *installed* packages. `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade` can also pull in new- or even remove package *dependencies*. <sup>1 2</sup>

But what if a completely brand new package is added to the OS release/repository as in my previous examples? Do I have to keep up with a blog somewhere so that I know to manually install newly released packages?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Neat commands like `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt full-upgrade` is basically the same thing as `upgrade` but handles dependencies differently - exactly how is beyond me.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> The upgrade is limited to "bug fixes and security patches"
 (see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports)).</sub>

## Some docs

[`apt-get upgrade`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) says:

> Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and
>   upgraded; under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or
>   packages not already installed retrieved and installed.

[`apt upgrade`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/apt.8.html) says

> New packages will be installed **if** required to satisfy dependencies [...].

## Other distros

As an added bonus, maybe the Linux guru would like to add a note on how all of this is handled on other distros.

To be honest, I am not really sure I have understood how releases, packages, and repositories all relate to each other and it might be some missing pieces of information related to this that clouds my mind. In particular, it became very cloudy when I read up on *rolling* distros lol.

Anyways.. many many big thank you's!

Comment: Your question is quite broad and other distros are lengthy and off topic

Comment: When Ubuntu updates your machine every few days or every couple of weeks the biggest stability changes are probably at the kernel level. That said a "glitch" in a google chrome update would probably be most noticeable to you. Like @Panther says though your question is broad and I'm voting to close as **too broad**.

Comment: "Will a newly released package be pushed to my machine?" - too broad?

Comment: I thought this was about *automatic* upgrades, or a server somewhere "pushing" data to you (they don't AFAIK, so that answer's "No"). Maybe narrowing it down to "what's the difference between all these similar "upgrade" commands?"

Comment: hahah no I am not asking about the difference =) I don't see how I can have screwed up so hard but apparently I have. I am wondering how new packages added to the repository get sent to my machine if I don't know to install them manually. For example, Canonical decides they need to add package ´x´ because it is critical to my system's security. I.e., not minor- and patch upgrades of installed packages, but *new* packages considered as a part of the OS.

Comment: I **think** the answer to my own question is simply that no *new* packages are ever added to the official repository after an OS release. Whatever security patch happens after the release must be done through a non-major upgrade (unless it is a "backport" which might upgrade major versions too) of an already installed/released package. But, I can't back this with official docs and I've been googling like crazy.

Comment: I made a big update to the question. Maybe it's easier to understand the question now?

Comment: You have to either manually upgrade them with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` or configure unattended upgrades as per the link I Gave you.

Comment: Generally speaking _new_ packages will not get added to a released version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @dobey: I encountered a few packages that don't appear in the base repository for release `X` but do appear in `X-updates`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster hence the term "generally." There have been cases where a security fix necessitates adding a new package in -updates as a dependency. But this is not done as a general solution for adding new packages. That's what -backports is for.

Answer (score 2):

When a security fault is found in product A, a new package for product A is released, with a higher version. This is updated in the package lists, which are part of the repository.

When your run `sudo apt update`, you download a list of packages available. Later, when you run `sudo apt upgrade`, given that you have product A installed, you will download the new version and install it.

If you do not have product A installed, the package will not be downloaded, nor installed.

Your whole system is packages. If a security problem is found in a component, for instance the kernel, *that* package will be updated, to a new version, but with exactly the same package name.

So this effectively ensures that you get the security patches that is appropriate for the software you have installed.

If you've installed software via other means than the Ubuntu repositories, you will *not* get updates for them via the Ubuntu repositories.

This is somewhat different from the Windows model, where you get updates, and it doesn't really tell you what module or part of the OS that is updated, nor can you choose what to install. But in Ubuntu (and other distros) everything is a package - and you can choose from a very minimal system, weighing in at under a gigabyte, without any graphical environment, to a full desktop - or server.

Right now I have one package that can be updated at a box I have - firefox:

```
[~]$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firefox
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/43.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

let's have a look at this package, using `apt-cache policy firefox`:

```
[~]$ apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 57.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
     57.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
[~]$
```

Here it shows that I have 57.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 installed, but 57.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is available. If I choose to upgrade, I will get the new version of firefox.

The `xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04` is kept back in above example, because it depends on `xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04`, which is not installed. Thus `apt upgrade` will not touch it, unless I do a `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04`:

```
[~]$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xserver-xorg-legacy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So a package will only be upgraded as long as it doesn't list new dependencies.

Comment: You have update first

Comment: Could you expand on that somewhat enigmatic comment? If I've forgotten something - by all means feel free to modify :)

Comment: Sudo apt update updstes the package list. You forgot this crutial step

Comment: I omitted it on purpose, but I see that this was a bad decision. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes in a way that is the step the op missed in reviewing upgrades or new packages or so ir seems

Comment: I read his question as more of a background question, to understand how the update system works, but that's fine :) I think we answered two slightly different interpretations of the same question :)

Comment: Agreed it os a long question. First sentence *"how and when a new package that was added to one of the machine's known repositories finds its way to my machine: . Thst part is update

Comment: *"Windows model, where you get updates, and it doesn't really tell you what module or part of the OS that is updated, nor can you choose what to install"* - You could still pick & choose the MS updates last I heard (<win8, has it changed?), and their info/web pages are sometimes quite detailed, they put many terse linux changelogs to shame. But updating the random win software you found from a random website/guy...

Comment: lol maybe I could have found a better way to describe my issue, but I am not asking about upgrading already installed packages. I am wondering how new packages that are added to the repository find their way to my machine unless I explicitly install them. Sure, upgrading installed packages is a no-brainer. But what if Canonical decides that they need to add a completely new package to the os release/repository? Say package `this-is-the-first-release-of-a-brand-new-firewall-thing-1.0´. Without this package, my computer is at risk (in theory).

Comment: vidarlo, in your example, isn't it true that `dist-upgrade`/`full-upgrade` would have installed the latest Firefox **and** the new dependency? I can not find that this is stated in the man pages, but if my memory serves me right then a full upgrade does install *new* packages all the time. I always thought these new packages were new dependencies.

Comment: That's true, yes. That is the main difference. dist-upgrade is willing to install new packages to fulfill dependencies. As for installing completely new packages: I don't see why you would have a need for that? It could theoretically be listed as a new dependency of a package, so it would be installed by a dist-upgrade.

Comment: I can't really think of any security problem that would **require** new software on the computer, to resolve the problem. If it's a bug an update of a package can fix it. But for a *totally* new piece of software? I can't really imagine what kind of situation that would be.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian / Ubuntu you have to update the package list and then upgrade

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Other distros are a bit off topic bit some distros combine these 2 steps into 1

On fedora for example you just

```
sudo dnf upgrade
```

On Ubuntu you can enable automatic upgrades if you wish

askubuntu.com/questions/9/how-do-i-enable-automatic-updates

See man apt

update (apt-get(8))
           update is used to download package information from all configured
           sources. Other commands operate on this data to e.g. perform
           package upgrades or search in and display details about all
           packages available for installation

do-release-upgrade upgrades to a new release or version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an authoritative answer, it basically only documents pieces of my own semi-shallow understanding.

New packages are never considered to be bug- or security fixes <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. They are considered to be new programs and new features of the OS <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. New packages are never added to an Ubuntu release because it is "[froozen](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/ReleaseProcess#Stabilization_.28Freeze.29)".

New packages are added to the next Ubuntu release, which should be finalized within [6 months](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Even removing an already released package "[is not technically possible](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Package_Removals)" and must instead be emptied.

At the end of the day, I guess the examples put forth in the question - however valid they might seem to be - has never happened in real life? E.g. Canonical never had to drop in an independently *new* package as part of a bug- or security fix.